# JavaScript CPQ Calculator Field not showing in Javascript Debugger Code

Tags: javascript, cpq-plugins

I am writing a custom Javascript script for CPQ. I created 2 new fields on QuoteLine. Product Type(pickList) and Target Price(currency). I filled data in on the record. I cant for some reason see Product Type in the debugger or in javascript. I do however see Target Price. I have done a SOQL query and I can see it exists just apparently not in Javascript. Any idea as to why or what i can do?

```
if (lineModels.length) {
lineModels.forEach(function(line) {

  console.log('Target_Price__c' + line.record['Target_Price__c']);
  console.log('Host__c' + line.record['Host__c']);
  debugger;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, after hours of research it appears that the fields must be in a field set within CPQ.... If not in a field set then any new field will not show in JavaScript Calacultor....!!!!